# Returning a function with the arguments reversed

Tags: javascript

The code that I am practicing with is where I have a function called InReverse. This function accepts a function as an argument and returns a function. When the function returned is invoked, it reverses the order of the arguments.

When the returned functions are returned:

const catDog = ('cat', 'dog') => returns ('dog cat')

What I have rewritten out so far is:

```
function inReverse (func) {
return function (...arguments) {
    return arguments.map((element) => {
        element.reverse();
    });
}
```

}

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply call the input function inside the newly created anonymous function.

For example this works:

```
function inReverse(f) {
     return function () {
         let args = [...arguments].reverse();
         return f.apply(this, args);
     }
}
```

So for example if you have `subtract` function like this:

```
function subtract(a, b) {
    return a-b;
}
```

`subtract(1, 10);` will be -9 as expected.

and `inReverse(subtract)(1, 10)` will be 9 as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using `map`, just call `reverse` right on the `arguments` array. Also you weren't calling `func`:

```
function inReverse(func) {
    return function(...args) {
        return func(...args.reverse());
    };
}
```

<sub>(Notice that `arguments` is a reserved identifier in strict mode, you should name your parameter for something else)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why you are using map method, just use reverse method in your function right on the arguments. Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse?retiredLocale=id

Answer (score -1):

Just reverse the arguments, and use func.apply(this, arr)

```js
function inReverse(func) {

  return function() {

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    args = args.reverse();
    return func.apply(this, args);
  }
}

function div(a, b) {
  return a / b
}

console.log(div(1, 2))
console.log(inReverse(div)(1, 2))
```